# how zab promise client FIFO order

Tags: apache-zookeeper, consensus

I want to know in the following situation, how zookeeper promise client FIFO order.

the client sent three operation to server,  set a = 1, set b = 1, set ready = true.

is it possible to this situation that the set a = 1 is process by the leader, then there is something wrong with this tcp connection, this client reconnect a new tcp connection to the leader, but the set b = 1 operation is on the way. then the client will use the new tcp connection to sent set ready = true operation.
so the set a = 1 is operated, set b = 1 is not and set ready = true is operated too.

the question is how zab promise client FIFO order?

zab can resend all the operation that hasn't be replied from the leader. then in this situation, when the client reconnect to the leader, it will resent the operation set b = 1, set ready = true.

is this the way the zab used to primise FIFO order?

Thank you all

Comment: Why would the client send ready=true if it hasn't received confirmation that a=1 and b=1 were successfully committed?

Comment: zab promise that these operation are sending in pipeline, so the later operation don't need to wait the prior's confirmation

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? Also, the FIFO order is per-connection. If you make a different connection, as far as zab is concerned you have a new FIFO channel and are a different client, so past commands are not ordered. In other words, the bug here is that when the connection was lost, the client resumed where they left off while assuming their previous commands were committed, which they have no evidence for.

Comment: @GManNickG   the document is diego's phd paper. in 11.1.2 section.
It's said that "Zab presents a slightly stronger guarantee than Raft for clients issuing concurrent requests. If a client pipelines multiple requests, Zab guarantees that they are committed in order (if at all); this property is called FIFO client order."

Comment: I think my conjecture is correct: if a client pipelines multiple requests _over the same FIFO channel_, Zab will apply them in that order. You don't get this guarantee with requests over multiple FIFO channels, as in your example.

Comment: ok. thank you. However, I think raft also promise this guarantee, why diego said that zab present a slightly stronger guarantee than raft?

Comment: Raft doesn't require FIFO channels to work (e.g. Raft over UDP) so it does not provide this guarantee. This also means a conforming Raft over TCP implementation could internally reorder requests from the same client if it felt like it. In practice, I would expect a typical Raft implementation using TCP to essentially process client requests in FIFO order, but as far as Raft is concerned it doesn't really have to. This is what they mean when they say that Raft could provide this guarantee (since the leader gets to choose the order), but some care would need to be taken to order the requests.

Comment: thank you. A typical raft always implementation using TCP, such as logcabin, etcd. so you mean that a raft implemented with TCP definitely support client FIFO order.   And a typical raft implemeatition won't change the order,  this is the same as zab.

Comment: Possibly. Unless the documentation for each says something about applying commands received over a consistent connection in order, I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: ok, can I say client FIFO order is easy to implement in raft.  And FIFO order is a such nice property for the user, I can't find any reasons why raft implementation won't support it.

Comment: I agree, it would be a nice feature. :)

Comment: in the end, thank you @GManNickG  for solving my confusion

Comment: @GManNickG   I got this information from zookeeper's paper 
"FIFO client order: all requests from a given client are
executed in the order that they were sent by the
client."  I think mayby zab only promise channel FIFO order, and then zookeeper use the zab's channel FIFO to implement client FIFO order.  the way maybe add a sequence number in each request, and resend the request if some sequence number don't arrive